# How do I run django test case?

Tags: django, unit-testing, twisted

I am using twisted to pass in a variable into my django environment so I have to run the twisted server. Hence when I am testing my django app I really need to run the twisted code

it runs something like this:

```
def wsgi_resource():
    pool = threadpool.ThreadPool()
    pool.start()
    # Allow Ctrl-C to get you out cleanly:
    reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('after', 'shutdown', pool.stop)
    wsgi_resource = wsgi.WSGIResource(reactor, pool, WSGIHandler())
    return wsgi_resource

wsgi_root = wsgi_resource()
reactor.listenTCP(DJANGO_PORT, server.Site(wsgi_root))
```

How do I even begin testing for this piece of code? 
I have to run twisted because my views uses something like this:

```
blockingCallFromThread( reactor, engine.push_message, user_hexid, room_hexid, message)
```

to call the variable that I passed into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write tests with [Twisted's built-in test runner, trial](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedTrial), assuming that you start your WSGI threadpool before each test and stop it afterwards (in setUp and tearDown).

The upcoming 11.1 release includes new documentation for doing test-driven development with Twisted using Trial.  Until that's available in the official location, here's a [temporary link to a buildbot build](http://buildbot.twistedmatrix.com/builds/sphinx-html/486-16033/projects/core/howto/trial.html) of our the documentation.